# Prob find latest collection

Tags: node.js

I don't find much information about this problem to solve.

On my mongodb I create a collection every 60 seconds with the name `"test "+ date.now()`. So far everything works ok. It creates me different collections with the name `test XXXXXX1`, `test XXXXX2` etc.

I have problems with the `mongoose.find()` method. I can't find my last created collection.

```
let test = mongoose.model('test' + date.now(), Schema);
test.find({}, function (err, response) {});
```

How do I find the latest collection in stream? Thank you!

Comment: based on your description, you can define a variable for date.now() and then create your collection, I think there must be a problem on using date.now()

Comment: thanks for the answer, then to create the collections I have no problem with date.now ().the problem lies in the find method because it looks for non-existent collections

Comment: then with the method "find (). sort ()" I can read the last collection created?

Answer (score 0):

Mongo ,By default , **does not support sequence** .
for that purpose you're going to have to add specific field for sorting or sort your fields based on your current field properties.
After that you have to use `.sort()`  cursor method :

```js
Collection.find().sort([...]);
```

[Read this article for more info](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/)